# Достоинства и недостатки PHP и ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, веб-программирование, php

Какие сравнительные плюсы и минусы есть у PHP и ASP.NET как технологий для создания сайтов?

Comment: Как правило на ПХП лучше, проще, быстрей, стабильней и дешевле. 
Фейсбук и Вконтакте выбрали ПХП. Думайте. 

Comment: ФБ и ВК для выбора языка не показатель.

php проще и легче это да, но технологии для разработки нужно выбирать в зависимости от сложности проекта и наличия опыта работы с теми или иными, опят же таки, технологиями.

Comment: Какого рода проект планируете разворачивать? На каком уровне владеете данными технологиями?

Comment: @master sporta Мы изменили Ваш вопрос, чтобы он в большей мере соответствовал формату форума.

Answer (score 8):

ASP.NET проще PHP в том смысле, что нужно меньше писать для решения одной и той же задачи. Аутентификация, авторизация, сохранение состояния перегружаемой страницы, гриды с автоматической привязкой данных, AJAX и прочие типовые вещи - встроены в ядро ASP.NET. Кроме того, архитектура классического ASP.NET является компонентно-ориентированной, то есть Web-страница представляется как форма, на которую можно кидать контролы и компоненты, подписываться на их события, а инфраструктура ASP.NET сама разрулит это так, чтобы у пользователя отрендерился нужный html + javascript, реагирующий на его действия таким образом, чтобы логика обработки этих событий исполнялась на сервере. Ещё одним плюсом ASP.NET является то, что приложение пишется на строго типизированных компилируемых .NET языках и поэтому технология существенно упрощает отладку по сравнению PHP.

Но лёгкость в разработке имеет свою цену в виде трафика. Для того чтобы эта инфраструктура работала, каждое действие пользователя требует перезагрузки всей страницы или хотя бы обновляемой панели AJAX. Кроме того, для того чтобы страница при перезагрузке без дополнительных действий со стороны программиста сохраняла введённые пользователем данные, эти данные должны быть продублированы в невидимом компоненте, который называется ViewState, и размазанный в строку битовый массив нехилого размера гоняется туда-сюда вместе со страницей. Так что за простоту разработки в случае использования ASP.NET WebForms платит конечный пользователь.

Технология ASP.NET MVC - это попытка приблизить ASP.NET к PHP по производительности. В этой технологии происходит отказ от компонентной архитектуры в пользу серверных вставок и выделения Master-страниц. Master-страница представляет собой шаблон, на основе которого создаются конкретные страницы путём вставки в указанные места шаблона специфического контента. Весь контент пишется на чистом html + javascript + серверные вставки, позволяющие при рендеринге страницы вставлять в неё код, сгенерированный контроллером, написанным под CLR. Таким образом, ASP.NET MVC - это отказ почти от всех преимуществ классического ASP.NET, кроме строго типизированного языка для разработки логики, ради борьбы с основным недостатком этой технологии.

Comment: 1. То, что вы написали, - это фича ASP.NET, а не особенность; вполне можно размещать обычные формы, а не WebForms, также можно отключать это для определенных компонентов. 2. Вопрос был не про ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Что касается "обычных форм", то эта же задача решается использованием Macromedia Dreamweaver. То есть, html controls - это просто component-style дизайнер для html-страниц. А специфические возможности ASP.NET предоставляет именно WebForms.

Answer (score 6):

Нет плюсов и минусов - есть разные концепции.

- ASP.NET ориентирована на большие проекты. PHP для более мелких проектов.
- ASP.NET считается более правильным, PHP более совковым.
- Под PHP есть много библиотек, когда пишешь под ASP.NET компонент - второй раз писать его не придется.
- Разработчики ASP.NET получают больше разработчиков на PHP.
- PHP интерпретируется, ASP.NET компилируется
- ASP.NET чуть медленнее работает с малой нагрузкой, с большой за счет компиляции работает быстрее (источник не помню где-то прочитал)
- У PHP - множество шаблонизаторов на выбор, у ASP.NET шаблонизация заложена в основу

Стабильность зависит от рук сисадмина.

По поводу того что ASP.NET только под Windows - [ASP.NET под линукс](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET).

Comment: А какой сложнее из них? Вот я в начале взялся изучить пхп, но потом, как-то, узнал про ASP.NET. Теперь же читаю Тролсена.

Comment: Проще php. Он создан для мини сайтов изначально, поэтому достаточно легкий в изучении.

Comment: Php создан для мини-сайтов? Вы откуда будете? :) ASP.NET - это очередная задумка Microsoft, чтобы срубить бабла, а php - это открытый проект. Это как сравнивать linux и windows. Если Вы не понимаете, как работает linux и для чего он нужен, то администрируйте windows :)

Comment: >> чтобы срубить бабла, а php - это открытый проектОпомнитесь. О чём вы говорите и какое это имеет отношение к вопросу? Разве вопрос был об открытости? ASP .NET - это законченная полноценная enterprise-платформа, а PHP - игрушка, переросшая себя и используемая всюду и всеми как попало. И не надо пытаться притягивать за уши холивары windows vs linux. Они тут неуместны. Опять страя песня: в неумелых руках из чего угодно плохо сделать можно. В действительности же, кадры решают ;)

Comment: Согласен :) Решают те, кто пишет :) В неумелых руках можно сделать и php и asp.net плохими :) php просто распространен больше, а asp.net уже сдох еще на стадии asp. Серьезные приложения писать говорите? Какие, например?

Comment: Да и вообще, как можно сравнивать компилятор и интерпритатор?)

Comment: На ASP.NET пишут большие и серьезные проекты не надо тут разводить бредовые рассказы. И не надо тут про то, что ASP.NET не пашет под линуксами: это тоже бред. Я не просто так написал, что разницы нет. Если честно, то я бы с удовольствием писал под ASP.NET, но не умею, а руки до изучения пока не дошли.

Comment: >> Да и вообще, как можно сравнивать компилятор и интерпритатор?)  Это тоже не имеет никакого значения в данном контексте. Вы всё пытаетесь куда-то свернуть в сторону. Но в правильных руках ASP .NET лучше годится для долгоиграющих больших приложений, чем PHP, так как PHP со временем тянет проект ко дну.

Answer (score 0):

по мне PHP лучше. на нем можно программировать хоть на телефоне. да и держать сервер на винде помоему это жоско...

Comment: ASP еще не значит что сервер должен быть на винде

Comment: asp есть и на линукс